# How to $emit from child to parent in Vuejs for reset data list

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a parent component that contains this code:

```
mounted() {             
  var self = this;

  this.getCandidates();
  this.$on('updateListCandidates', () => {
    self.getCandidates();
  });
 },
```

Thanks to this I can update my list by calling `$emit ('updateListCandidates')`

I have a child component that I import like this:

```
<DeleteCandidate :item="scope.row"></DeleteCandidate>
```

In this child component, I have a Destroy function. I ask it to refresh my list thanks to `$emit` once the element correctly deleted.

```
async destroyItem() {
        await this.deleteItem.delete(`candidates/${this.deletingItem.id}`)
          .then(() => {
            this.$emit('updateListCandidates');
            this.$message({
              message: `Candidate (${this.deletingItem.full_name}) correctly deleted.`,
              type: 'success'
            });
          });
      },
```

BUT it doesn't work.

Why ? And how to solve my problem?

If I do that in my parent component, it works. I think it's because I'm in a child component but I do not know at all how to do a `$emit` on a parent in this case

I specify that my candidate is deleted well. I do not have any error messages in the console.

Thank you

Comment: `this.$on` will listen for an event emitted by the component itself. To listen for an event emitted by a child component you need to set up an event listener on the child component with `v-on` or the shorthand `@`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, why don't you remove this code

```
  this.$on('updateListCandidates', () => {
    self.getCandidates();
  });
```

and directly call `getCandidates` instead of doing `$emit ('updateListCandidates')`?

Secondly, (the answer to your actual question) you must listen to event in direct parent and perform action there whenever you emit from child. Otherwise just emitting from child (and not listening in parent) will not effect anything. So you can do in parent

```
<DeleteCandidate :item="scope.row" @updateListCandidates="getCandidates"></DeleteCandidate>
```

I assume `getCandidates` is defined in parent.